# Using Selenium WebDriver in custom extension

Tags: webdriver, firefox-addon, dom-events, selenium-firefoxdriver, xpi

I am developing a Firefox extension and have a need to generate synthetic events. I want this events to be treated as 'native' events. However, the DOM APIs exposed by Firefox (createEvent, initEvent) aren't really behaving as native events.  I realized Selenium solved the issue by adopting native events.

My question is, can I use webdriver.xpi standalone within my extension? My extension is JavaScript based. If yes, how? Has anyone done it before?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are events generated by Firefox extension 'trusted'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456705/are-events-generated-by-firefox-extension-trusted)

Comment: Agreed. My question here is a bit different, but the answer for the other question solves the problem I was trying to solve using Selenium's webdriver.xpi.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is unnecessary:

> You can use [nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendMouseEventToWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMWindowUtils#sendMouseEventToWindow%28%29) instead of document.createEvent(). This method is meant for testing and will generate a native event as well.

**References**

- [Are events generated by Firefox extension 'trusted'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456705/)