# Simulating mouse events in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need to simulate trusted mousemove event in JavaScript. As I read there:

http://help.dottoro.com/ljoljvsn.php

> In Firefox, an event is trusted if it is invoked by the user and not trusted if it is invoked by script.

And after that I started search other solution. I found this:

[Are events generated by Firefox extension 'trusted'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456705/are-events-generated-by-firefox-extension-trusted)

> Yes, events generated by extensions are always trusted.

So, now I want write FireFox extension to allow me create mousemove trusted event. Unfortunately, I've never written extensions FireFox, so I need to clarify some points. What I have:

1. I downloaded example of XPI file
2. I created install.rdf and bootstrap.js for bootstraped extension (like FireBug)

But now I don't understand:

1. In this article:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous#Simulating_mouse_and_key_events

i see code:

```
var utils = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                      .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils);
utils.sendMouseEvent("mousedown", 10, 10, 0, 1, 0); utils.sendMouseEvent("mouseup", 10, 10, 0, 1, 0);
```

what point in bootstrap.js I must insert this code? How I understand I must attach it in some active(or specified?) window.

2. How can I can run extension code in my JavaScript like global object "console" in FireBug extension?

I would appreciate an explanation

Comment: You can put that in the startup of your bootstrap addon. It will run right away. You need to access a `window` because bootstrap scope has access to no window. You can access the most recent `navigator:browser` window (a window which has tabs) by toing `var window = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')`. Make sure to import `Services.jsm` like this: `var {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu} = Components; Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');`

Comment: Thank you. I another question: how can i create global JS object in extension? Because when i try: 
var window = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
window.test = {};
I don't see it in my FF console.

Comment: You can access bootstrap scope of addon from everywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057888/controlling-a-firefox-extension-via-javascript/22099148#22099148