# Use a chrome://myAddon/content/ URL in Firefox Add-on SDK extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to load a frame script following this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Frame_script_loading_and_lifetime):

```
mm.loadFrameScript("chrome://myextension/content/content.js", true);
```

My extension is an Add-on SDK type. The tutorial says I need to specify `content` in `chrome.manifest` first. I did not even have that file (only `package.json` and `index.js`). So I've created `myextension/chrome.manifest` with a single line:

```
content content.js
```

And created a file `myextension/content/content.js`:

```
console.log("content script executed");
```

The problem is, when `mm.loadFrameScript("chrome://myextension/content/content.js", true);` is executed in `index.js`, I get error:

```
No chrome package registered for chrome://myextension/content/content.js
```

I guess it is because the manifest file is wrong or not being registered all together? But I couldn't find any clues to my problem on the [chrome registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial is generally targeted towards [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) or [restartless/bootstrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_Extensions) add-ons. A more appropriate tutorial in that hierarchy is: [Multiprocess Firefox and the SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Multiprocess_Firefox_and_the_SDK).  The gist of that page is that if you stay with the Add-on SDK APIs your extension should just work in multiprocess Firefox, and that if it doesn't then it is a [bug in the Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Multiprocess_Firefox_and_the_SDK#SDK_internal_incompatibilities).

In general, Add-on SDK extensions will use one of the [High Level APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs) to load [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts). The primary APIs which would be used are [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) and [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), but there are others (e.g. [context-menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) and [page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker)). There are also the [Low-Level APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs) of [remote/parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent) and [remote/child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_child) which deal with [processes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent#Process) and [frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent#Frame).

However, you can use [frame scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Frame_script_loading_and_lifetime) if you desire to do so.  Add-on SDK extensions are actually restartless/bootstrapped extensions which are wrapped by the add-on SDK. Thus, you can do most things which can be done in a bootstrapped extension within an Add-on SDK extension if you *really* want to do so. However, it is better to stay within the APIs provided by the Add-on SDK. If you go around those APIs then you loose some of the advantages which the Add-on SDK exists to provide to you (e.g. hiding the actual implementation behind APIs which are intended not to change).

Frame scripts and content scripts exist to perform the same function: access the content (e.g. HTML pages) which has been loaded into an area that is potentially under the control of a different process (e10s). Largely, the things that are referred to by the two different names are very similar. However, you will almost exclusively see the term "frame scripts" used only for XUL and bootstrap extensions while "content scripts" will almost always be referring to Add-on SDK scripts.

Again, you are probably better off using the Add-on SDK APIs to load the scripts you are using to access content that is potentially in another process.

### **Add-on SDK: Using the `data` directory:**

For an Add-on SDK extension, instead of using a `chrome://` URL it is more appropriate to use the *[add-on base directory]/data/* directory and obtain the URL reference to your file using the [`sdk/self` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self). You would do this with:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
let frameScriptUrl = self.data.url("content.js")
```

Then your [`loadFrameScript()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFrameScriptLoader#loadFrameScript%28%29) line would be:

```
mm.loadFrameScript(frameScriptUrl, true);
```

### Using *chrome.manifest*:

**[`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#content-instruction) lines:**
The `content` line of the *chrome.manifest* file is:

```
content packagename uri/to/files/ [flags]
```

This is a minimum of 3 fields separated by whitespace with one or more optional additional fields for [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#Manifest_Flags).

The first field is `content` which indicates that this is a line that defines how a `chrome://packagename/content` URL will be resolved.

The second field is a `packagename`. This is a name that you make up which must not conflict with other package names already in use by Firefox or those added by other extensions.  *Usually*, this will be the `name` you are using for your add-on, or some permutation of the `name`, or `id`, if using multiple `content` lines. The name and ID of your Add-on SDK are usually the value of the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#Key_reference) and [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#Key_reference) properties you included in your [*package.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) file, but may be [somewhat different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Program_ID). The `packagename` does not need to be your `name` or ID, it just needs to be unique to everything that was loaded into Firefox.

The third field is the URL to the directory which contains the files you are going to be referencing. This URL can either be absolute, or relative to the location of the *chrome.manifest* file. This URL must end with a `/`.

Firefox looks for the *chrome.manifest* file in the base directory of your add-on (the same one in which *package.json* is located). While it is possible to have additional *chrome.manifest* files using the [`manifest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#manifest) keyword, that would be unusual.

The prototypical add-on *chrome.manifest* would contain a line such as:

```
content packagename chrome/content
```

When using the chrome URLs made valid by that `content` line in your *chrome.manifest* you would use something like `chrome://packagename/content/myScriptFile.js`. This would reference a file called `myScriptFile.js` that is in the *[add-on base directory]/chrome/content/* directory.

**Another example:**
*chrome.manifest*:

```
content myAddOnName my/special/directory/
```

In this case, `chrome://myAddOnName/content/myScriptFile.js` would reference the file *[add-on base directory]/my/special/directory/myScriptFile.js*.

**Your specific issue:**
While you stated you were following the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Frame_script_loading_and_lifetime), you did not actually do so for the contents of your [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration) file. Nor when you changed what that file contained did you follow the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#content-instruction) of what the `content` line should contain. However, even if you had followed the tutorial exactly, you would not have ended up with a functioning add-on because the tutorial was incorrect as to what should be in that file. The line in the tutorial was actually invalid. I have corrected that line in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Message_Manager/Frame_script_loading_and_lifetime#chrome_URLs).

What you need to use as the line in your *chrome.manifest* will depend on the directory structure you desire to use for your extension.

If you wanted your *content.js* to exist in a directory *[add-on base directory]/chrome/content/* and be referenced by `chrome://myAddOnName/content/content.js` then the `content` line of your *chrome.manifest* would be:

```
content myAddOnName chrome/content/
```

Note: Even though you used `myextension` in your question (in your `chrome://` URL only) for your `packagename`, I have not used it here to try to more clearly indicate that the `packagename` should be a name you choose which is unique to your add-on. It is not clear to me that you are using `myextension` in your question as a placeholder for what you are really using within your extension. If that is the actual text you are using rather than a placeholder for your question, then I would caution you that the packagename `myextension` is not very unique and has a reasonable chance to exist in some other random extension. If it does, it may, or may not, cause either or both of your extensions to malfunction.

Comment: I appreciate such a detailed answer. You talk about content scripts and frame scripts. You suggest to use content scripts in Addons SDK because it is covered by SDK. Can you tell me if content script is possibly in my use case: I need to use `nsITextInputProcessor` Low level API in that tab. Here is a stackoverflow answer which suggested me to use frame scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526708/1132711

Comment: @alandarev, In the comments on that answer, I suspect that "frame scripts" were understood to mean any scripts, including content scripts, which run in the process controlling the web page content. I suggest that you start a new question. Make that question about your overall goal implemented in the Add-on SDK, not specific to how you are currently attempting to implement it. Do include the code you are currently trying to use, but as something like "I have attempted to accomplish this with A) code, reasons why it did not work for you; and B) code, reasons why it did not work for you; etc.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK provides an abstraction for frame scripts and process scripts (beyond the page-mod and tab attach mechanisms which also rely on frame scripts under the hood), the [remote/parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_parent) and [remote/child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/remote_child) modules. You can use `remote_require` to load a process script and then use remote/child in the process script to enumerate the sdk wrappers for the frame script global objects.