# How to set a created event's `isTrusted` property in javascript using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, dom-events

I would like to create and fire a KeyPress Event through a userscript in Greasemonkey but I observed that the createEvent's `isTrusted` is set to `false` all the time.

`isTrusted` is read-only property but I read that it can be set to True by extensions like Greasemonkey but it's not working for me.

Is there a way to set `isTrusted` to `true`?.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You cannot currently do this with Greasemonkey.  For the most part, Greasemonkey just runs javascript, and javascript can't set `isTrusted`.  It would defy [the spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-istrusted) and defeat the whole purpose of trusted events.

That said, theoretically, [a Firefox add-on should be able to spoof `isTrusted`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456705/are-events-generated-by-firefox-extension-trusted), but Greasemonkey has not extended that capability to its users.

There is [**a feature request to add `isTrusted` capability to Greasemonkey**](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2301).  You can go there and add your voice to the discussion, or you can fork the Greasemonkey code and add the capability yourself.

---

There is [a related question for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34853588/how-to-trigger-an-istrusted-true-click-event-using-javascript), but spoofing `isTrusted` may not be possible in that browser, even for extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you could create a trusted event with a WebSocket that JavaScript uses to communicate to a Python script running in the background which would press the key, but that's a lot of code.

Python code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import pyautogui
async def watchlist(websocket, path):
    while (1==1):
        key = await websocket.recv()
        pyautogui.press(key)

start_server = websockets.serve(watchlist, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

JS code to press key:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765")
function sendkey(key){
     ws.send(key)
}
sendkey('a')
```

Comment: Any ground for this claim? I don't see anything that would make this possible.

Comment: Python code: 
import asyncio
import websockets
import pyautogui
async def watchlist(websocket, path):
    while (1==1):
        key = await websocket.recv()
        pyautogui.press(key)

start_server = websockets.serve(watchlist, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

Comment: And how does this help in overriding the frozen `EventInstance.isTrusted`?

Comment: Because when python simulates a keypress, it creates a trusted event for Chrome

Comment: but will this work on a background page or tab?